# How can I use inheritance and swagger mechanisms in my API at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Most of my methods in the API are implemented according to the following scheme:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SomeController : ApiContriollerBase<SomeRequestModel>
{
    public override void Method1() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}


[Produces("application/json")]
public abstract class ApiContriollerBase<TRequest> : ControllerBase
    where TRequest : new()
{
    TRequest ApiRequest = new TRequest();

    ApiResponse ApiResponse = new ApiResponse();

    [HttpPost]
    public ApiResponse EntryPoint([FromBody] TRequest request)
    {
        // Do something. Method1(), Method2()...

        return ApiResponse;
    }

    // Some virtual methods
    public virtual void Method1() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public virtual object Method2() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

When I try to use swagger, it fails to generate swagger.json and gives an error: "Fetch errorundefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json". As far as I understand, swagger cannot understand my request mechanism. I really don't want to change this circuit because of swagger. Is there any other way to fix the error?

Comment: What framework/library do you use - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, something else?

Comment: I use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.